Dataset of 2D/3D potential energy surfaces, excited states
I see several research papers with excited and ground state PES of different molecules showing level crossings and intersections. But, I do not find any database publicly available. Is there any datasets that have E vs x v y that is freely available online? For example H3+ molecule is heavily studied but, I do not find any dataset of 2D/3D both ground and excited state.

+1. Welcome to our community.
